# How to compile project with only `mvn clean install` without having to subsequently run `mvn install`?

Tags: mapstruct, maven-compiler-plugin, immutables-library

I am trying to compile project which uses both `Mapstruct` and `Immutables`. The only solution which solves my problem is to run:

1. `mvn clean compile` -> fails with compilation failure; cannot find generated classes from `Immutables`
2. `mvn compile` -> succeeds

Which is not acceptable for me.

I've tried recommended solution which you can see in the code section.
I've also looked at:

- https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1596
- https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1270

...

```
<mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Beta2</mapstruct.version>
<immutables.version>2.7.3</immutables.version>
```

...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                        <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                        <version>${immutables.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I would like to be able to only run `mvn clean compile` in order to get project compiled.

Comment: I cannot explain why there is an order issue here (did not see this before).. you could play around with the order of executions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243912/changing-the-order-of-maven-plugin-execution in the maven-compiler-plugin and the proc only option: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html this way you could proc-only immutable first and then run the compiler with mapstruct + compile

Comment: Are you using Immutables in the mappers? Can you also try to define the order of the processors in `annotationProcessPaths` and see if that helps? In any case as @sjaak said, the order should be irrelevant

Comment: I created minimal project to show you the issue, however, I was not able to reproduce it in it. ... I'll try to experiment more and return here if I find the more info. Thanks for now to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of building a minimal example of the issue I noticed this line which happened to be the cause of the failing build:

```
@Mapper(imports = {ImmutableFirstType.class, ImmutableSecondType.class})     // this one
public interface FirstSecondTypeMapper {
```

I thought `imports` are necessary in order to make `Immutables` with `mapstruct` work. Just used `@Mapper` and everything went fine.